# Adding a line to bar chart

Tags: python-pptx

I have a simple problem , i am trying to add a reference line on the head of a bar keeping my value axis line same. For example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrduR.png)

I want to add that blue line on the top of my reference bar.

Comment: Your image is not showing. Also, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Hi @scanny you will have to click n the link above to view the image.

Answer (score 2):

I used following code to insert a line into a PowerPoint slides using python-pptx. The parameters are left, top, width and height for each Inches listed below. Inches(0) in width parameter inserts vertical line and Inches(0) in height parameter inserts horizontal line.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE

prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blankSlideLayout)
line1 = slide.shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.LINE_INVERSE, Inches(6), Inches(6), Inches(1), Inches(2))
```